# React Native + Expo : save pdf/word doc from url and use Linking to Open the file in a different app

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been using the default create-react-native-app and would like to continue to do so as long as I can without ejecting.

The feature I need for the app is to download a file to the app cache using FileSystem.downloadAsync which stores the file to the local cache or temp directory. Next I need to share that file with any program that can open it. For example. if I download a word doc then open the word viewer, or if it's a pdf then open a pdf viewer.

Is it possible to open an app that can view those files and still use default create-react-native-app?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this exaple is [based in documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem.html):

https://snack.expo.io/BkT-AkAvm

Comment: Once it's downloaded how can it be opened? The example is pdf but there might be doc as well. I would expect that an open with...would show up and I would pick the app that handles those doc types

Comment: you can use [the shared of react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html) to open with another app or use a package to read the specific file

Comment: @Enieber is their any way i can download base64 qr code as a pdf? I generate base 64 qr code but cann't download since it using url!

Comment: @LearnwithPanda you can use the QR code like URL of pdf and make dowload of pdf.

Comment: I updated the snack expo to use sdk 38:

https://snack.expo.io/@enieber/pdf